# How to create Always Encrypted column encryption key from c# client

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I see that the various articles on SQL Server 2016's Always Encrypted feature describe creating the column encryption key using either SQL Server Management Studio UI or by using the [New-​Sql​Column​Encryption​Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/new-sqlcolumnencryptionkey?view=sqlserver-ps) powershell command. But what if the C# client application itself wants to create the column encryption key? What is the format of this `ENCRYPTED_VALUE` column?

```
CREATE COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY CEK1
WITH VALUES (
COLUMN_MASTER_KEY = CMK1,
ALGORITHM = 'RSA_OAEP',
ENCRYPTED_VALUE = ??????
```

Answer (score 4):

For the Certificate Store provider, you can use the [SqlColumnEncryptionCertificateStoreProvider.EncryptColumnEncryptionKey Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcolumnencryptioncertificatestoreprovider.encryptcolumnencryptionkey.aspx), e.g. as shown below:

```
var randomBytes = new byte[ 32 ];
using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rng.GetBytes( randomBytes );
}
var provider = new SqlColumnEncryptionCertificateStoreProvider();
var encryptedKey = provider.EncryptColumnEncryptionKey( masterKeyPath, "RSA_OAEP", randomBytes );
var encryptedKeySerialized = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString( encryptedKey ).Replace( "-", "" );
```

Credit to [this blog post](https://justdaveinfo.wordpress.com/2015/10/15/always-on-encrypted-generating-certificates-and-column-encryption-key-encrypted_value/) for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This was just what I needed. I couldn't find a way of doing this without powershell until this. It's quite easy to get it to work with Key Vault also, just change the provider.